# Why am I getting a capture-of applicability error in my class?

Tags: java, list, generics

I wrote the following code:

```
public class HashMapImpl<Key,Value>{
    Key key;
    Value value;

    List<? extends Key> keylist;
    List<? extends Value> valuelist;

    public HashMapImpl(Key k,Value v){
        this.key = k;
        this.value = v;

        keylist = new ArrayList<Key>();
        valuelist = new ArrayList<Value>();
    }

    public Value put(Key k, Value v){
        this.keylist.add(k);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on `add()`:

> The method `add(capture#3-of ? extends Key)` in the type `List<capture#3-of ? extends Key>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Key`)

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Another thing that is wrong is that there's not return value in the method `put()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to use `? extends Key` in this use case; that syntax is for a list type that **could be more restrictive, but isn't necessarily more restrictive than `Key`**. Because the compiler doesn't know that it's just a `List<Key>`, it won't let you add `Key`, because of the case where the generic type of the list *does happen to be more restrictive than `Key`.

One way to think about it is that, in the case of `Collection`s:

- It's easy to `add` stuff to `List<? super Foo>`, but you don't know much about the object; `get(int index)` returns an `Object`, not a `Foo`.
- It's hard to `add` stuff to `List<? extends Foo>`, but you know a lot about the object; `get(int index)` does return a `Foo`.

**tl;dr** Just use:

```
List<Key> keylist;
List<Value> valuelist;
```

and your program will work.

Further reading: [Canonical Java Generics FAQ, with a link to the section on bounded wildcards](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ301)